# Apollo React graphql - how to share data transforms between components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am working or a React application which uses Apollo's GraphQL.

In the application, I fetch data using hooks, and transform it to better suit my internal structures.

These transformations can be quite costly, performance wise.

Furthermore, I can have 4-5 separate components which call the same query and thus perform the same transformations.

I am looking for a way, without success so far, to have components share the transformed values and use them directly, meaning that if another component performed them then they won't.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue in an app which I've solved by creating an object which can be *loaded* via a GraphQL query and then *getted* by any component. In my app this is only done at startup but there's no reason it couldn't be done more often.

```
let transformedData;

export const myObject = {
  async load() {
  const { data, error } = await client.query({ query: myQuery });
      if (data) transformedData = transform(data); // some expensive function
      } else if (error) throw new Error(error);
  },
  get() {
    return transformedData;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am using Apollo's react hooks, and I need it to be so that when the value changes than the components will re-render.

Comment: Without checking at intervals..

Comment: Please show what you've built so far then and we can go from there.